# How do I forward an action to another controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, forward

Rails 4 - I have an action that handles routes like `www.site.com/catalog/shoes/sport/ABC123` for product and `www.site.com/catalog/shoes/sport` for category
The problem is I have to display some seo-paid links (not my choise, I just have to) in format `www.site.com/href`, and that link must me handled as some product category. That's not the only case - in future, there might be some other "short"-links, that are pointing to other parts of my site

When I used Symfony, I could just write `$this->forward('controller', 'action')` and get another controller's output while saving short route, but in Rails I see only redirect_to, and it does not preserve short url?

Assuming I have a route `get ':href' => 'index#simple', as: :simple`, how do I forward execution to another controller (or just call controller's method?), preserving original route? - In "rails way", of course

Thank you

Comment: So, I found partial solution for my needs - I added
ProductSet.find(:all).each do |ps|
  get "#{ps.href}", :to => "catalog#category", :set => ps.href
end
to routes.rb - so now I wonder how do I dynamically reload routes when I add new ProductSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use 'redirect_to controller_action_path' / redirect_to '/controller/action' from your controller action.